# Using ArcPy & UniqueValueRenderer to assign specific colors to points based on value

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, symbology, color, rendering

I have code that amends the symbology of a layer in ArcGIS Pro 2.9 via an IDE. Everything works apart from the color of the points, which appear to be being picked at random (different every time I run the script) and not the specified red & green in the code.

There are only two unique values in the Total_Score field. The size & outline color look correct, so the IF statement appears to be working as expected, just not the color statement. No errors are being produced.

From looking at the ArcGIS Pro Help webpages, my code should work but isn't. Any ideas?

```
if mfName == fldName:
    sym = lyr.symbology
    sym.updateRenderer("UniqueValueRenderer")  

    sym.renderer.fields = ["Total_Score"]      # sets field

    # applying symbology to each defined value
    for grp in sym.renderer.groups:
        for itm in grp.items:
            myVal = itm.values[0][0]
            print("myVal: {0}".format(myVal))

            if myVal == 1:
                itm.symbol.color = {"RGB": [249, 30, 22, 0]}        # red
                itm.symbol.outlineColor = {"RGB": [0, 0, 0, 0]}     # null colour for symbol outline
                itm.symbol.size = 5
                itm.label = str(myVal)

            elif myVal == 3:
                itm.symbol.color = {"RGB": [78, 247, 30, 0]}        # green
                itm.symbol.outlineColor = {"RGB": [0, 0, 0, 0]}     # null colour for symbol outline
                itm.symbol.size = 5
                itm.label = str(myVal)

    lyr.symbology = sym     # apply defined symbology back to layer
```

Comment: You could manually set all the symbology you want in Pro, then using your Python code, output the `symbol.` > properties and compare that syntax to yours, making sure it's correct.

Comment: Don't know if this is an issue but the help on [symbol](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/symbol-class.htm) says - _The alpha or opacity value behaves the opposite way as transparency in the application user interface. If you set this value to 100 in the dictionary, it will appear as a 0% in the transparency control on the ribbon or in the Symbology pane._?

Comment: @KHibma How do I do this? I'm relatively new to Pro.

Comment: @Hornbydd I saw this but it isn't the transparency that is the issue, it's the colors.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not working as expected for two reasons:

1. Values although numeric are string
2. You set the alpha to zero which according to help is 100% transparent

So your code should be:

```py
if mfName == fldName:
    sym = lyr.symbology
    sym.updateRenderer("UniqueValueRenderer")
    sym.renderer.fields = ["Total_Score"]      # sets field

    # applying symbology to each defined value
    for grp in sym.renderer.groups:
        for itm in grp.items:
            myVal = itm.values[0][0]
            print("myVal: {0}".format(myVal))

            if myVal == "1":
                print("num 1")
                itm.symbol.color = {"RGB": [249, 30, 22, 100]}      # red
                itm.symbol.outlineColor = {"RGB": [0, 0, 0, 0]}     # null colour for symbol outline
                itm.symbol.size = 5
                itm.label = str(myVal)

            elif myVal == "3":
                print("num 3")
                itm.symbol.color = {"RGB": [78, 247, 30, 100]}      # green
                itm.symbol.outlineColor = {"RGB": [0, 0, 0, 0]}     # null colour for symbol outline
                itm.symbol.size = 5
                itm.label = str(myVal)

    lyr.symbology = sym
```